# Android - Manual "Automatic" DayNight change on onResume triggers caught exception (Performing pause of activity that is not resumed)

Tags: android

I'm adding a Day/Night mode to my app, but my app does not request location services for various reasons, so the automatic modes times of 10/6 don't work for my app.

I'm using my own times which will work fine given the use case, but I'm running into a problem on automatically changing them smoothly.

If the app is restarted, the switch works correctly, as the values get set in the application class, but if they app is already opened, I need to trigger it in the onResume or onStart as far as I can tell.

If I call  `getDelegate().applyDayNight();` to trigger to switch in onResume, this caught exception gets thrown (no app crash)

```
E/ActivityThread: Performing pause of activity that is not resumed: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing pause of activity that is not resumed:
at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3196)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3184)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3159)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:144)
```

The exception makes sense, I'm interrupting the onResume and the activity is getting re-created by the day/night application. I did some looking, and for things like this people suggest using a handler to delay post it, but when I do that, I see a flicker of the color changes, rather than the app simply opening with change which is a much better user experience.

This is the code I'm using in onResume

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int currentNightMode = AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode();

            ((MyApplication) getApplication()).updateNightModeFlag();

            if (currentNightMode != AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode()) {
                getDelegate().applyDayNight();
            }
        }
    }, 0);

    super.onResume();
}
```

A couple questions

1 - Is there a better way to be doing this so the app will switch the next time the app resumes after the sunset/sunrise time and not have it flicker with the change and not throwing the exception.

2 - Is the exception actually bad and going to cause me problems in some unknown way now, or in the future, if there is no better way than what I'm doing right now, and decide to take it out of the handler for the smooth transition?